# MySQL - UPDATE returns syntax error using serialized data

Tags: mysql, serialization, syntax, sql-update, syntax-error

I'm having troubles with this command

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(
  meta_value, 
  'a:1:{s:6:"seller";b:1;}', 
  'a:1:{s:11:"wcfm_vendor";b:1;}')
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_capabilities'
```

I get a syntax error `near ''a:1:{s:6:"seller")' at line 3.`

If i run this one ...

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
SET meta_value = 'a:1:{s:11:"wcfm_vendor";b:1;}'
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value LIKE 'a:1:{s:6:"seller";b:1;}'
```

I also get the error `near ''a:1:{s:11:"wcfm_vendor")' at line 1.`

But this one works...

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta
SET meta_value = REPLACE(
meta_value, 
'6:"seller', 
'11:"wcfm_vendor')
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value LIKE '%"seller"%'
```

Comment: Must work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a16754275cdddfca7bca4dfb18af7aa5 Provide a fiddle with your structure and sample data which reproduces your issue.

Comment: So you mean the syntax is ok and the command should work?

Comment: I use your query text without any edition - and it works. I treat this as "the syntax is correct". But I cannot say that the query itself is "ok" - `WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_capabilities'` is the same as `WHERE meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'` but needs more work for the server.

Comment: This worked `SET meta_value = REPLACE( meta_value, '6:"seller', '11:"wcfm_vendor')
   WHERE meta_key LIKE 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value LIKE '%"seller"%'` Maybe it has to do with these "" in the serialization

Comment: This is serialization from PHP looking point only. But from MySQL looking point this is common string value (including doublequote chars). PS. `AND meta_value LIKE '%"seller"%'` condition is obviously excess. If it is not true then the substring to be replaced is absent in the value.